# Giving permission to anyone (non-users as well) with a password to edit a post, possible?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, password, capabilities

I would like to make possible to any visitors (non-users) to create a custom post from the WP frontend, then get a password in email which can let him/her edit the post if the proper password is given.

Now my focus is only on the capabilities part. Is there a native WP solution to make a [CPT](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types) post editable to non-users who can enter the required password to that specific post?

**I would like to avoid generating extra number of Users for this feature, if possible.**

*:The created post would be assigned to the Admin by default.

Thank you for any alternatives!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a generic form that can be completed by the public on the front end.  The submission of the form would would generate the post, saving a random string in its meta data (the password), and send an email containing a link to `/?p=PAGEID&post_id=THE_POST_ID&pw=THE_PASSWORD`.  *THE_POST_ID* and *THE_PASSWORD* are those values from the post generated, and the *PAGEID* is a page you created that contains shortcode to handle the editing.  Not to get too far into detail, but your shortcode would be something like this:

```
add_shortcode('viktor_edit_post', function() {
    // Sanitize
    $_REQUEST['post_id'] = absint($_REQUEST['post_id']);

    // Validate
    if(empty($_REQUEST['post_id'])
    || get_post_status($_REQUEST['post_id']) === FALSE
    || get_post_meta($_REQUEST['post_id'], 'pw', TRUE) !== $_REQUEST['pw']
    ) {
        // I would suggest echoing the public form here and handling its submission
        // here as well.  I think it would be preferable as you need not hard-code
        // the PAGEID because this shortcode sits on that page.  You could get it by way
        // of the global $page (as done below).
        return;
    }

    // If edit submission, update.
    if(wp_verify_nonce('viktor_nonce_'.$_REQUEST['post_id'], 'viktor_check')
    && isset($_REQUEST['new_post_content'])
    ) {
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID'            => $_REQUEST['post_id'],
            'post_content'  => sanitize_textarea_field($_REQUEST['new_post_content']);
        ));
    }

    // Display edit form
    global $post;
    ?><form action='/?p=<?= $post->ID ?>' method='POST'>
    <?php wp_nonce_field('viktor_check', 'viktor_nonce_'.$_REQUEST['post_id'], FALSE); ?>
    <input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='<?= $_REQUEST['post_id'] ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='pw' value='<?= $_REQUEST['pw'] ?>'>
    <p><?= sprintf(
        __('Please make changes as you see fit to %s.'),
        get_the_title($_REQUEST['post_id']),
    ) ?></p>
    <textarea name="new_post_content"><?= get_the_content(NULL, FALSE, $_REQUEST['post_id']) ?></textarea>
    <?php submit_button('Save'); ?>
    </form><?php
});
```

The deal here is that you're not messing around with capabilities, which control the users of your site.  As you want to deal with non-users as well, I think a simple shortcode plugin is the way to go.